# embedding MS-word documents in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-office

I was curios to know wheather it was possible to embed MS-Office documets in html without using any third party application as shown [here](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-embed-microsoft-office-or-pdf.html).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to embed MS-word documents without third party plug-ins.  MS-Office formats are not web-standards and browsers do not natively understand them.

They can be rendered by using a browser plug-in that understands the MS-Office format, by converting the MS-Office documents to HTML or by converting the MS-Office documents to PDF and using the Adobe PDF plug-in to render them.

Comment: The new MS-Office x format is (docx, etc) is open and xml based; and JavaScript has support for binary data. So the newer versions should be able to embed it without converting to pdf, or something like that?

Comment: @Bakudan-ханювиги - 'open' does not mean it's a standard that all browsers have built-in support for - it only means that MS has published the format.  Yes, it's XML, but XML is just a bunch of data until something understands what the data means and knows what to do with the data and how to render it.  That would require MS-Office-specific code which is not built into any browser that I know of.  It's possible that Microsoft might build that into IE, but I sure doubt other browsers are going to build that in.  The document format of the web is HTML, not Office XML.

Answer (score 0):

That particular example involves using a third party Flash application that is delivered to the browser.

You don't "need" something like that. Using an `<object>` element should allow you to embed arbitrary media in a document.

However, browsers do not support Microsoft Office data formats, so they would need a plug-in in order to support it. Microsoft Office tends to install one but you can't depend on users having it installed. (Plenty of people don't have Microsoft Office, I carefully rip out because I'd much rather that following a link to a Word document resulted in it opening in an application and not throwing a pile of toolbars into my browser, platforms where Office doesn't run (mobile in particular) are growing, etc).

If you want to deliver an Office document for reading over the WWW then you are best off converting it to HTML in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's relying on Google Docs in an iframe to render the Word document into HTML, but it's possible to use this code in your webpage:

```
<iframe style="width: 900px; height: 900px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=urltoyourworddocument&embedded=true" height="240" width="320" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

http://christopher.su/2012/embedding-documents-google-docs/